# Modifying `sakila` database

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, mysqli

This is not "real life" code.  I'm trying to expand upon the well known `Sakila` sample database for MySQL to make it more complex. Step 7 (or 6) is running surprisingly slow.

PS: Note these are all separate queries executed against the same database in the order specified.

1. Add columns to `sakila.customer` table:

   ```
   USE sakila;
   ALTER TABLE customer
       ADD COLUMN multiplier DECIMAL(3,2) AFTER active;
   ALTER TABLE customer
       ADD COLUMN cust_ranking VARCHAR(10) AFTER multiplier;
   ```

   Duration: 0.289 sec
2. Create a proc to randomly distribute multiplier:

   ```
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_randCustMult;
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_randCustMult()

   BEGIN
       -- declare a counter
       SET @start = (SELECT MIN(customer_id) FROM customer);
       SET @stop  = (SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM customer);

       -- start while loop
       WHILE @start <= @stop 
           DO
           -- select a random float variable
           SET @RAND = RAND();
           -- update NULL field
           UPDATE customer
           SET multiplier = (SELECT 
               (CASE
                   WHEN @RAND <= 0.65 THEN 1.00
                   WHEN @RAND <= 0.90 THEN 0.85
                   WHEN @RAND <= 1.00 THEN 1.05
                   END))
           WHERE customer_id = @start;
               -- tick counter one up
               SET @start = @start + 1;
       END WHILE;
   END//
   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Duration: 0.001 sec
3. Call the proc to populate the rows:

   ```
   CALL sp_randCustMult;
   ```

   Duration: 0.761 sec
4. With Safe Update Mode OFF, add human-friendly values to `cust_ranking` based on multiplier.

   ```
   UPDATE customer
       SET cust_ranking = 'Standard'
       WHERE multiplier = 1.00;
   UPDATE customer
       SET cust_ranking = 'Premium'
       WHERE multiplier = 0.85;
   UPDATE customer
       SET cust_ranking = 'Uplift'
       WHERE multiplier = 1.05;
   ```

   Duration:
   0.057 sec
   0.037 sec
   0.035 sec
5. Add a `real_amount` column to table `payment`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE payment
   ADD COLUMN real_amount DECIMAL(5,2)
   AFTER amount;
   ```

   Duration: 0.749 sec
6. Create another proc to populate `payment` with real amounts:

   ```
   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_RealAmtPayment;
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RealAmtPayment()

   BEGIN
   -- declare a counter
   SET @start = (SELECT MIN(payment_id) FROM payment);
   SET @stop  = (SELECT MAX(payment_id) FROM payment);

   WHILE @start <= @stop
   DO
       UPDATE payment AS p
           INNER JOIN customer AS c
               ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
       SET real_payment = (p.amount * c.multiplier)
       WHERE p.payment_id = @start;
       SET @start = @start + 1;
   END WHILE;
   END//
   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Duration: 0.001 sec
7. `CALL sp_RealAmtPayment;`

   Duration: 17.082 sec
8. `SELECT * FROM payment;`

   1000 row(s) returned
   0.002 sec / 0.002 sec

Step 7 seems extremely long considering the very small number of records.  What am I missing? All comments/critiques welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never played with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), so this may be completely wrong, but if I get it right the `WHILE` loop would be the equivalent of a T-SQL `CURSOR`, which is inherently slow.

You're essentially looping on `payment_id`, incrementing at each iteration - this *assumes* the ID's are contiguous, which isn't a safe assumption to make with data: if records were deleted, you have more iterations than records:

> ```
> SET @start = (SELECT MIN(payment_id) FROM payment);
> SET @stop  = (SELECT MAX(payment_id) FROM payment);
>
> WHILE @start <= @stop
> DO
>     UPDATE payment AS p
>         INNER JOIN customer AS c
>             ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
>     SET real_payment = (p.amount * c.multiplier)
>     WHERE p.payment_id = @start;
>     SET @start = @start + 1;
> END WHILE;
> ```

In pseudo-code, this can read as follows:

- For each `payment_id` in `payment`...
- ... update the `real_payment` column to `p.amount*c.multiplier`

I don't see why you need a loop to do this, I think this would be equivalent... and faster:

```
UPDATE payment AS p
    INNER JOIN customer AS c
        ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
SET real_payment = (p.amount * c.multiplier)
```

Answer (score 7):

Similar to Mat's answer, in stage 2, you are calculating a random value for each customer, and processing the customers one-at-a-time.

It would be faster to process them all together, but, the rand() becomes hard to do because it changes value each time you call it, and you need to change the 'obvious' odds of things as you go.

Your procedure (with [a test SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b5e14/1/0)) can be reduced to:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_randCustMult;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_randCustMult()

BEGIN

        SET @first = 0.65;
        SET @second = (0.90 - @first)/(1.0 - @first);

        -- update NULL field


        UPDATE customer
        SET multiplier = (SELECT (CASE 
                WHEN RAND() < @first then 1.0
                WHEN RAND() < @second then 0.85
                ELSE 1.05
            END));
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Cool I'll delete the data tonight and test those 2 scripts and post results. One thing I love about SQL is that the most elegant scripts are the simplest ones.

Comment: Duration: 0.036 sec. Everything seems spiffy and in proportion.